# how to create unique id for each department in django model

Tags: python, django

i created a model in django for student information

```
<!-- language: python -->
class student(models.Model):
    department_choices=(('cse','cse'),('mech','mech'),('EEE','EE'))
    name=models.CharField(max_length=35)
    department=models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=department_choices)
```

i want id to be generated unique for department for example if i chose cse department id should be cse0001, cse002 or if mech means id should be mech001 , mech002 what should i do

Comment: You can create a Departmen model and linke Student to Department via ForeignKey

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement for `department_id` is that it is simply unique you can use the `Student` primary key. So unless you absoutely need the `department_id` stored in the database. I would determine it on the fly after you have retrieved the student instance from the database.

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    DEPARTMENT_CHOICES=(('cse','cse'),('mech','mech'),('EEE','EE'))   

    name=models.CharField(max_length=35)
    department=models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES)

    def department_id(self):
        return f"{self.department}{self.id}"
```

This will append the `Student` primary key to the department string.

You can use it in your templates like this.

```html
<ul class="student">
  <li>Name: {{ a_student.name }}</li>
  <li>Dep ID: {{ a_student.department_id }}</li>
</ul>
```

If you need to display this in the Django admin you can add to the above `department_id` method like this.

```py
def department_id(self):
    return f"{self.department}{self.id}"

department_id.short_description = "Department ID"
```

You can now use `department_id` as a read only field in the Django admin.

Lastly, if you want the ID to have leading zeros you can use `zfill()`.

```py
def department_id(self):
    return f"{self.department}{str(self.id).zfill(4)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having a `Department` model firstly, but if you really need this on the `Student` model. I'd add an extra field to your model, then populate it when the model saves. That way you can ensure uniqueness and use it in any ORM filtering or other operations:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    department_choices = (('cse', 'cse'), ('mech', 'mech'), ('EEE', 'EE'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=department_choices)
    department_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check here for PK, PK will only be populated if save()
        # has already been called before, so this means the
        # department_id field will only be set when the model is created
        # remove this condition if you want it regenerated after every save() call.
        if not self.pk:
            self.department_id = f"{self.department}{self.pk}"

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, an `IntegrityError` will be thrown if you try to create a student which has an existing `department_id` as we can enforce uniqueness with the `unique=True` argument on the `department_id` field.